# remove emoji from string in R

Tags: r, regex, twitter, unicode, substitution

I have a list of tweets, many of which contain emojis that need to be removed.  What would be the most effective method for doing this in R?

I have tried the following method which is supposed to substitute all words beginning with "\" with a blank, but I receive this error

```
some_tweets <- gsub("\\\w+ *", "", some_tweets)
Error: '\w' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\\\w"
```

Here is a sample of the data:

```
> head(some_tweets)
[1] "ஆமா நான் பாக்கவே இல்லை \U0001f625\U0001f625\U0001f625"                               
[2] "எனக்கு அனுப்பலாமே \U0001f913\U0001f913\U0001f913"                                  
[3] "அவர் ஏன்டா ப்ளாக் பண்ணார் \U0001f602\U0001f602\U0001f602\U0001f602"                        
[4] "ஆமா"                                                                           
[5] "RT : சும்மார்றா சுன்னி.. ~ ஆதவன்"                                                      
[6] "கைலியை எல்லாம் லூஸ் பண்ணிகிட்டு உக்காந்து இருக்கேன் அடுத்து போடுங்கயா \U0001f608\U0001f608\U0001f608"


> dput(head(some_tweets))
c("ஆமா நான் பாக்கவே இல்லை \U0001f625\U0001f625\U0001f625", 
"எனக்கு அனுப்பலாமே \U0001f913\U0001f913\U0001f913", 
"அவர் ஏன்டா ப்ளாக் பண்ணார் \U0001f602\U0001f602\U0001f602\U0001f602", 
"ஆமா", "RT : சும்மார்றா சுன்னி.. ~ ஆதவன்", 
"கைலியை எல்லாம் லூஸ் பண்ணிகிட்டு உக்காந்து இருக்கேன் அடுத்து போடுங்கயா \U0001f608\U0001f608\U0001f608"
)
```

Comment: You are just using `gsub` and are not using a regex. You need to use a regex.

Comment: Does `\\\\w+ *` work?

Comment: I tried `\\\\w+ *` but it does not work

Comment: What should the output look like?

Comment: it should retain all of the Tamil characters while all of the emoji symbols (beginning with "\U" should be removed

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check out [regular-expressions.info on Unicode](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html), which has a thorough explanation of Unicode in regex. The part that matters here is that you can match Unicode characters with `\p{xx}`, where `xx` is the name of whatever class they're in (e.g. `L` for letters, `M` for marks). Here, it seems your emoji are in the `So` (shorthand for `Other_Symbol`) and `Cn` (shorthand for `Unassigned`) classes, so we can sub them out with:

```
gsub('\\p{So}|\\p{Cn}', '', some_tweets, perl = TRUE)
## [1] "ஆமா நான் பாக்கவே இல்லை "                                       
## [2] "எனக்கு அனுப்பலாமே "                                           
## [3] "அவர் ஏன்டா ப்ளாக் பண்ணார் "                                       
## [4] "ஆமா"                                                        
## [5] "RT : சும்மார்றா சுன்னி.. ~ ஆதவன்"                               
## [6] "கைலியை எல்லாம் லூஸ் பண்ணிகிட்டு உக்காந்து இருக்கேன் அடுத்து போடுங்கயா "
```

Note you need `perl = TRUE` set, as this notation is not enabled in R's default POSIX 1003.2 regex; see `?base::regex` and `?grep`.

Comment: Thanks alistaire -- I had the same issue and your solution works fine.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link to the detailed regex info so I can start to patch up my own solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily remove all emojis from a string in R this way:

```
library(rtweet) # To get emojis dataset
emojis # Look at emojis

library(stringr)
str_remove_all(string = emojis$code, pattern = '[:emoji:]')
```